# Jenkins CI - Allowing a job to run (triggered manually) only if a specific list of jobs are "blue" (successful)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to achieve that? getting the status of other jobs and checking if last run was "success"?

I don't want to automatically run this deployment job on the upstream success, but to trigger this manually. but still safeguard by checking upstream (multiple) success

Thanks for the help